# how to allow a hidden button to be shown when focused using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I have a container `div` and it has a hidden `button` inside it and it appears only when focusing on the container `div`. I want to make the `button` visible when focused (I want to make it focusable). Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6m51xdtb/1/)

`HTML`:

```
<div class="ads" tabindex="0">
  <button class="close" tabindex="0">X</button>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
.ads{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0.5625rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.03125rem;
    border-color:  lightgrey;
    background-color:  #ffffff; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
.close{
      display: none; 
      padding: 0; 
      background: transparent;
      border: none; 
      margin-top: 0.5rem; 
      margin-right: 0.5rem; 
      float: right; 
      width: 0.5rem;
      height: 0.5rem;
      background-image: url('delete.png'); 
      background-size: 100% 100%;
}
div.ads:focus{
    background-color:  #ebeded;
}
div.ads:focus .close{
  display:inline-block;
}
button.close:focus{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: focus... focusable... what?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan  yes to make the event :focus on it with the tab key

Comment: it's working actually. look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6m51xdtb/3/) I changed the background on focus so you can see (i'm using chrome)

Comment: @avrahamcool it focuses only the container div ,but I want to focus also after that the button itself

Comment: @user6561572 don't forget that as some point TAB key fill start focusing other element in the browser...

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan you are right ,but why don't I see the button focused? it has the tabindex="0" so it should be

Comment: Can you explain why you need `tabindex` on that  DIV in the first place?

Comment: yes , I'm doing a school project and this is a requirement

Answer (score 1):

At any given moment of time only one element can be in focus or none.

But your solution assumes that there are two elements matching `:focus` in the document at the same time.

Here is sequence of events when you press TAB on focused div:

1. Your div looses focus so is does not match :focus;
2. Button gets hidden as it has not got focus yet;
3. as nothing visible/focusable inside the div focus moves to something else but not to the button.

You should find other solution.

Update: possible CSS only hack is to use opacity:0 instead of `display:none`.
Hack here is that `opacity:0` element is considered as still displayed element so focusable.

```css
input{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.ads{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0.5625rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.03125rem;
    border-color:  lightgrey;
    background-color:  #ffffff; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

.close{
      opacity: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      background: transparent;
      border: none; 
      margin-top: 0.5rem; 
      margin-right: 0.5rem; 
      float: right; 
      width: 0.5rem;
      height: 0.5rem;
      background-image: url('delete.png'); 
      background-size: 100% 100%;
}

div.ads:focus{
    background-color:  #ebeded;
}
div.ads:focus .close{
  opacity: 1.0;
}
button.close:focus{
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="press on me and tab two times">
<div class="ads" tabindex="0">
  <button class="close" tabindex="0">X</button>
</div>
<p>
 by the second tab you should see focused button ,but you don't
</p>
```

Comment: but when I :focus on the button I make it visible by display:inline-block isn't that enough? I think I am messing something between

Comment: At #1 your div has no :focus and button has no :focus yet. So it is invisible/not-focusable

Comment: Nice step-by-step explanation.

Comment: thank you for explaining further, I understood the problem. So is there some other way to do that  only in css?

Comment: @user6561572 "do that only in css" - I don't think you can do that in CSS. Script in needed.

Comment: okay.. can you guide me please how to do it by JS? by an answer or articles to read ..

Comment: @user6561572 I still think you completely misunderstood the requirement. If JS was meant to be used than it should've been stated by such "requirement"...

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I also thought that at the first place but actually the requirement says clearly that both the container div and the button must be 'focus-able' with the tab key

Comment: @user6561572 I've updated my answer with "CSS only" hack

Comment: @user than, if clearly you have room for improvements and addons - simply put the button in a parent div - abdplute positionet to top right. So actually ypur focusable DIV and BUTTON will become siblings.

Comment: don't use opacity 0 to "hide" actual action elements or youll be in big trouble. My suggestion/idea would be using negative `z-index` instead, to bring the button behind the DIV (making impossible to perform an accidental UI action on such element. Or as I stated before - make both the div and button siblings of a common wrapper.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan using z-index is a good idea, I will do it that way . And yes I can see that the answer above makes the button invisible but even clickable and that is really a problem. Any way, thanks for c-smile and you for making it clear to me ,your explanations made me understand better now.